# How did the Doctor meet Vastra, the Silurian?

Tags: doctor-who

Vastra is a Victorian Silurian, one of a race of reptilian humanoids buried in caverns in the earth.

She is first seen in the television series in ['*A Good Man Goes to War*'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Good_Man_Goes_to_War), wherein the Doctor calls upon her in his time of need.

When did the doctor first meet her? Does/did she owe him, if so what for?

Comment: So far that is my all fav ep of DW.

Comment: Wasn't it said that she first met the Doctor in a subway tunnel while trying to avenge her sister's death ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, we have never seen or heard any more of her story on screen besides the small amount of exposition we get in that episode. She was awoken due to construction in the London Underground, the Doctor stopped her from rampaging through London, and she became a detective-like character working with Scotland yard and "ate" Jack the Ripper.

The companion book [The Brilliant Book 2012](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849902305) has more information about her exploits, depending on how strict your interpretation of Doctor Who canon is. Even those stories, though, don't tell us much about her first meeting with the Doctor.

OOU: There was apparently interest in making a spin-off with her and her human companion, which is why they were given such a seemingly-involved back story on their first appearance, but it probably won't happen any time soon.

Comment: A spin off would be epic.

Comment: @Pureferret that appears to be the general consensus among fans, but Moffet has flat out said he doesn't have time for it yet. :(

Comment: All I need is block of wood and a sledgehammer...

Comment: Would love to see that spin-off. As well as the HG Wells (Warehouse 13) spin-off which is also supposedly somewhere in the making.

Comment: I'd watch "The Madam Vastra and Jenny Show" like CRAZY.

Comment: @DanRay ...and Strax

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Who says Moffat has to write it? (other than Moffat...)

Answer (score 2):

All the [wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Vastra) says on her is stuff you'll discover if you watch the episode.

She woke up when some miners accidentally killed  bunch of her *sisters*. She was angry and killed a bunch of them before the Doctor stopped her.

Which is the same thing she repeats to the Doctor in the scene where the Doctor get angry. (and renames Colonel [Manton](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Manton), Colonel Runaway.)

Answer (score 0):

The following quote can be found on the [TARDIS Wikia](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Vastra), does it not answer your question?

> Vastra was one of many people who owed the Doctor a debt; she had
>   awoken during the construction of part of the London Underground and
>   sought to take revenge on the innocent tunnel workers responsible for
>   the accidental deaths of her "sisters". After Vastra had slaughtered
>   at least five commuters, the Doctor convinced her not to give in to
>   her rage. He also told her of his species, the Time Lords, sharing
>   many secrets about them, including the Untempered Schism, the time
>   vortex and their ability to regenerate. At the the Doctor's
>   insistence, she ceased her attacks on the tunnel workers and instead
>   integrated herself into humanity's Victorian culture, eventually
>   gaining the title of 'Madame' and taking up residence at Paternoster
>   Row.